# Show drupal login on page load

Tags: 7, ajax

I want to display the login form in a popup when a user is not logged in (meaning Anonymous).

I read [this tutorial](http://www.deeson.co.uk/online/labs/advanced-ctools-run-ctools-javascript-call-any-time?nocache=1#comment-89), but when I try nothing happens, so I think maybe it's because I am on Drupal 7? How is jQuery called in Drupal 7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be a good idea to see [this podcast](http://mustardseedmedia.com/podcast/episode2).

Comment: Thank you for the link, it helped me alot to understand Javascript on drupal,also i checked some Lullabot videos.And  Above all i was able to display the login form on page load...after getting  reply from the same person who wrote the article i posted early but now updated it to drupal 7. here is the link for anyone interested.   http://www.deeson.co.uk/online/labs/trigger-drupal-managed-ajax-calls-any-time-drupal-7

Comment: Your link is helpful for me!it's really interesting.Good luck